# Erro: package javax.servlet does not exist import javax.servlet.*

Tags: java, java-ee, aplicação-web

Eu criei os diretórios corretamente, copiei o código e agora  não compila e retorna esse erro. Estou compilando pelo terminal usando o javac.

http://pastebin.com/WLaGQit3

```
package com.example.web;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;

    public class BeerSelect  extends HttpServlet {

        public void doPost ( HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response )
            throws IOException , ServletException{

            response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                out.println("Beer Selection Advice <br>");
            String c = request.getParameter("color");
                out.println("<br> Got beer color " + c);

        }
    }
```

Stacktrace no terminal:

> ```
> src/com/example/web/BeerSelect.java:3: error: package javax.servlet does not exist
> import javax.servlet.*;
> ^
> src/com/example/web/BeerSelect.java:4: error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
> import javax.servlet.http.*;
> ^
> src/com/example/web/BeerSelect.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
>     public class BeerSelect  extends HttpServlet {
>                                      ^
>   symbol: class HttpServlet
> src/com/example/web/BeerSelect.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
>         public void doPost ( HttpServletRequest request,
>                              ^
>   symbol:   class HttpServletRequest
>   location: class BeerSelect
> src/com/example/web/BeerSelect.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
>             HttpServletResponse response )
>             ^
>   symbol:   class HttpServletResponse
>   location: class BeerSelect
> src/com/example/web/BeerSelect.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
>             throws IOException , ServletException{
>                                  ^
>   symbol:   class ServletException
>   location: class BeerSelect
> 6 errors
> ```

Comment: Você tem certeza que q servlet-api está no classpath da sua aplicação? Parece que não.

Comment: Não Sei.. como faço para saber? Eu configurei o ClassPath no terminal apontando pro jar do servlet

Comment: Poste os comandos que você usa no terminal para compilar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro exibido acontece porque o compilador não consegue encontrar e por conseguinte não consegue importar o javax.servlet, pois esse jar encontrasse dentro do servidor web. Para compilar adequadamente via linha de comando é necessário especificar o caminho para o jar:

`javac -classpath .:/caminho/para/o/jar/javax.servlet.jar com/example/web/BeerSelect.java`

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791446/compiling-servlets-with-javac